# RxJs interval throttle based on inner observables

Tags: javascript, selenium, rxjs

Apologies if the phrasing of the question is bad, it's because I can't come up with the proper words to describe it.

I am doing some Selenium automation and the flow is as below:-

1. Navigate to page
2. At interval of 1 second, check if page contains an element
3. If page contains the element, refresh the page, if not, go back to Step 2
4. Wait for page to finish reloading, before repeating Step 2

This is what I managed to come up with:-

```
interval(1000)
.pipe(
 switchMap(() => from(driver.findElements(By.xpath("elementx"))),
 filter(([element]) => element), // finish if no element found, wait for interval to trigger again
 switchMap(() => from(driver.navigate().refresh()))
).subscribe(() => {})
```

But I want the interval to stop emitting when selenium driver is waiting for `findElements` or `refresh`. What are the correct rxjs operators that I should use to achieve this?

Comment: Use timer rather than interval?

Comment: Or add a `take (1)` operator right after pipe?

Comment: So the problem is that `findElements` runs for very long time and before a single call completes `interval(1000)` makes multiple emissions? If that's the case you can use `exhaustMap` instead of `switchMap` and the intermediate emissions from interval will be ignored while `findElements` is running.

Comment: @martin if it was only `findElements` that I require then that would be the solution, but then I also need to depend on whether `findElements` returned something, if it returned something, I need to block interval emissions until `driver.navigate().refresh()` too, not sure what would be the combination for that..

Comment: @pandamakes I require the interval to keep scanning for the element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `exaustMap`, then rather than placing the continuation below the `exhaustMap`, place it within it (using an inner pipe), so that further emissions
will be ignored as long as the entire procedure has not been completed, as in the following example:

```
interval(1000)
  .pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => {
      return from(driver.findElements(By.xpath("elementx"))).pipe(
        filter(([element]) => element),
        switchMap(() => driver.navigate().refresh())
      )
    })
  ).subscribe(() => { })
```

p.s. (switchMap, mergeMap, concatMap) accept promises directly.